# Owl-carousel 2 stop the work of autoplay when lose a focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I use Owl-carousel 2. I use standard code of initialization and markup of Owl-carousel 2. At the first load of page the work of carousel is perfect.  Owl-carousel 2 stop the work when I pass in browser to another page and back or minimize browser and again open page with Owl-carousel 2. New start of carousel when I again click navigation. I had try to place in body of html code of initialization of carousel again:

```js
var $carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
var owl = $carousel.data('owlCarousel');
owl.trigger("refresh.owl.carousel");
```

But it is not working. Autoplay need to run but it is not working. How I can correct this problem? Thanks

Comment: There is a discussion (without a solution yet) in this GitHub topic, I'm following it. https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1674

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old, but since it has no answer yet, and the issue is still present in `Owl Carousel 2.2.1`, here's a simple solution that may hopefully help someone:

> Try using the beta build of Owl Carousel, you can get it [here](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/tree/develop/dist). Just grab the `owl.carousel.js` or `owl.carousel.min.js` file and replace the one you're using currently with it. At
>   the moment of this writing the current beta build is 2.3.0. I can
>   confirm that this build fixed the issue for me.

---

The issue is a [known bug](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1727). The discussion in the issue tracker provides more insight into what causes it, so you could use it to modify your existing `owl.carousel.js` to incorporate your own fix if you don't feel like using beta builds.